# Console App not working once deployed

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, console-application, unity-container

I have a very simple console application that works completely as expected on the dev machine. It throws no errors whatsoever. But, I moved it to the a test server (in hope of running it from a task manager) and I received errors, which I'll include below.

Project details: C# console app .NET 4.0 using Telerik Open Access ORM, Unity 2.1.505.0
Test Server: running .NET 4.5

Here's how I'm porting the app: I compile a release build and copy the Release folder to the test Server (is this the problem? I read elsewhere that this should work fine). Once on the test server, I double click the .exe in the copied release folder and receive this message:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: TheProgram.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 52f01aa9
  Problem Signature 04: Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
  Problem Signature 05: 0.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 0
  Problem Signature 07: 0
  Problem Signature 08: ffffffff
  Problem Signature 09: AVANCNVQQH3AW3N14UWVEHHCIAYOLYLS
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.274.10
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 8e3d
  Additional Information 2: 8e3d05599b3d6894d98ff944d1bc5d05
  Additional Information 3: 527f
  Additional Information 4: 527fbc2b98d11a1bd024767ee818ba21
```

The Event viewer of the test server contains the following error info:

```
Application: TheProgram.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(System.Type, System.Object, System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolverOverride>)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(System.Type, System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolverOverride>)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.Resolve[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolverOverride[])
   at TheProgram.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

This looks like Unity failing to resolve a dependency. But again, no errors occur on the dev machine.

The Unity setup is pretty straightforward. Most of it is in the Program.Main() method:

```
// Initialize Unity DI Elements
            var UnityContainer = new UnityContainer();
            UnityContainer.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            UnityContainer.RegisterType<IDataService, DataService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            UnityContainer.RegisterType<ISpreadsheetService, SpreadsheetService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            UnityContainer.RegisterType<IEmailService,EmailService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            UnityContainer.RegisterType<IDateService,DateService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());


            var data = UnityContainer.Resolve<IDataService>();
            var sheet = UnityContainer.Resolve<ISpreadsheetService>();
            var email = UnityContainer.Resolve<IEmailService>();
            var dates = UnityContainer.Resolve<IDateService>();
```

The Console output on the Test Server points to the first line of the second block - the one that resolves the IDataService.

The DataService is also pretty straightforward DI-wise. Here is its constructor information:

```
 public class DataService : IDataService
    {
        private readonly IRepository _repo;

        public DataService(IRepository repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }
```

And the repository has no dependencies (though I call Resolve<> on it anyway - is this a problem?)

I'm pretty new to Unity, but this seems like a pretty straightforward implementation.

Does anyone have any ideas why the error occurs when trying to run the .exe on the test server? Thank you!

UPDATE: The problem is occurring when I include the line: var data = `unityContainer.Resolve<IDataService>();`

Up to that point it works. This class also has a dependency as shown above IRepository gets injected into it's constructor - is this dependency being processed correctly? And is the syntax correct for Unity?

Second update: the app is no longer displaying errors. I found 2 problems... first, a dependency was not resolved in the code, so that was fixed; second, the app was looking for Telerik .dlls. I added those to the bin folders. After doing both of those things, the app worked as expected.

Comment: did you deploy all necessary dlls?

Comment: Is .NET 4.5 installed on your test server?

Comment: Yes, .NET 4.5 is installed on the test server. I'm going to check the .dlls - all have "copy local" set to true, but I need to confirm that the copying actually happened.

Comment: I tried the publish method for the app and it created a folder with a setup file in it - when I click on that setup on the server it tells me to install certain dlls to the GAC. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have to agree with thumbmunkeys. It is almost certainly an issue with a missing assembly or perhaps the incorrect version of an assembly. Check that and see.

Comment: That's where my thoughts are going, too. I'll check that out and see what I find.

Comment: Yes, there were missing .dlls, just not the ones I thought were missing.